# What's the equivalent of Java's computeIfAbsent or putIfAbsent in Clojure?

Tags: java, dictionary, clojure

With a map in Java you can write `map.computeIfAbsent(key, f)` that checks whether the key exists in the map already, and if not calls `f` on the key to generate a value, and enters that in the map.  You also have `map.putIfAbsent(key, value)` which only puts the value in the map if the key does not already exist in the map.

Ignoring the fact the Java methods also return the value, and instead wanting the new map returned, what would be the equivalent code in Clojure?

The best I've come up with so far is to roll my own with something like

```
(defn compute-if-absent [map key f]
  (if (key map)
    map
    (assoc map key (f key))))
```

Is there an alternative to rolling my own?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clojure maps are immutable so you will always return a new map with updated contents - thus your functions will be always thread safe. It also means that you can't have a global variable holding your map and mutate them in place.

Your implementation of `compute-if-absent` is almost correct. It will fail for keys that are falsey, for example `{false 1}`. You need to change your `if` condition and use `contains?` instead of `key`:

```
(defn compute-if-absent [m k f]
  (if (contains? m k)
    m
    (assoc m k (f k))))
```

If you do need to have the same behaviour as `ConcurrentMap` you can just use them using Java interop in Clojure.

Comment: I presume you mean "contains? m key"

Comment: Yes, I have fixed it.

Comment: I've marked this as the correct answer for the question as I've stated it, even though now I think I actually meant what z7sg is answering -- I've at least given that answer a vote too.

Comment: Presumably (defn compute-if-absent [m k f]
  (if (contains? m k)
    m
    (assoc m k (f k))))

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler solution would be to use `merge`, for `put-if-absent`:

```
(merge {key val} m)
```

Although the end result would be the same for `compute-if-absent`, the following code would of course compute `(f key)` regardless of the contents of `m`:

```
(merge {key (f key)} m)
```

Comment: don't think it is simpler than Piotr's one (shorter though): first of all you should always consider the parameters' order for `merge`, second: you call the `f` every time, even if the key is present in `m`, so when the value computation is heavy, it is a huge performance penalty (and if the value is computed with some side effects, it is even error-prone)

Comment: It is simpler for `put-if-absent` but not for the compute version, which I did mention in the answer. I would consider the use of an `f` with side-effects here error-prone, not the use of `merge`.

Comment: again, i'm not saying `merge` is bad, i just say that it is bad to call the function `f` *both* in case of presence *and* absence of a value in a map, instead of calling it only when there is no val. Also not saying that side effects are good, rather do i say that they are not impossible (like when value generation depends on items from the queue of some kind, there would be a lot of values from the queue "lost" (retrieved but not used). Or if this `f` function has logging inside, you would be probably having a fun time parsing the resulting log with the whole bunch of unwanted records)

Comment: I think the whole point of `compute-if-absent` is to generate the new value (call `f`) only when needed (e.g. it's costly or **has side effects**). Otherwise you could always use `put-if-absent` with the result of call to `f`.

Comment: Actually when I asked the question I just wanted a convenient way to put something in the map if it wasn't already there (I should have just asked about put-if-absent I guess).

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to implement some form of caching, then you can use clojure's great `memoize` function.

Example: `(def fast-inc (memoize inc))`

See: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memoize